# Block all user agents except one from htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, bots

I am currently using the following directives in my htaccess to block all bad bots.

```
ErrorDocument 503 "Sitio inhabilitado temporalmente para el rastreo"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(bot|crawl|spider).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

However, I would like to know how I can exclude the following bots:

SemrushBot-BA

SiteAuditBot

SemrushBot-SI

Thanks in advance

Note: A possible solution would be this?

So he final result would then be as follows...

```
ErrorDocument 503 "Sitio inhabilitado temporalmente para el rastreo"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(bot|crawl|spider).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(SemrushBot-BA|SiteAuditBot|SemrushBot-SI) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
```

Comment: Add a RewriteCond that checks the UA does _not_ contain any of these exact strings? Negation, even for regex patterns, can be done by preceding the whole pattern with a `!`.

Comment: Similar to this? RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(SemrushBot-BA|SiteAuditBot

|SemrushBot-SI) [NC]

Comment: Yes, something like that (minus the extra space after SiteAuditBot.)

Comment: @CBroe I have edited the question based on your answer, could you please check it? Thank you

Comment: Looks okay to me. Did it work? (If you need to test this, then installing a browser extension that allows you to specify which referrer to send, might be a good idea.)

Comment: I finally edited the htaccess file and it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

You are a good person.